# Cannot resolve "google.appengine.users"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am sorry for such a silly question but I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere on google funnily enough!

I have installed the google app engine SDK as mentioned on their [getting started page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/devenvironment). I have also installed the following over pip:

```
pip install webapp2
pip install WebOb
pip install Paste
```

However, I am having trouble importing the *google.appengine* package as shown in [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingusers).

I have tried searching all over the place for the package which contains this package path. I have installed the Google Python Client API using pip as follows:

```
pip install google-api-python-client
```

But still no luck....

Could someone please point in the right direction for this supposedly simple task? Is there a particular package I am missing?

I'm sorry for my ignorance regarding google app engine!

Comment: why on earth are you installing paste (you wouldn't use it in appengine), in addition why install webob, webapp2 etc.. as these come with the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're not launching your app with

```
python dev_appserver.py yourappfolder
```

You could also try adding the google appengine SDK folder to your PYTHONPATH

Comment: Can't believe this is the reason! Don't know why it didnt occur to me.

Comment: Setting PYTHONPATH fixed this for me. As someone was correct to point out, I don't even need to use pip to install those extra packages once the path is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just download it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) ? For example: get the .tar.gz or the .zip, extract your package and run 'python setup.py install'

Comment: How did it not work? What happened or what output did you get?

Comment: When I try importing as follows it just doesn't work: `from google.appengine.api import users`

Comment: Will try it out on my linux machine later, maybe I screwed up something in the installation process.